# How to extend a class in LESS on hover

Tags: css, less

Hi I was wondering how I can take styles from another class on a hover state in LESS.
At the moment I have:

```
.language .active {
    background:#de1f24;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:7px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3A3838;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.language a {
    color:red; 
    font-weight:bold;
}

&:hover{
    &:extend(.language);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fontSize{
    font-size:22px;
}

.box{
    color:#fff;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    font-size:14px;
    &:hover{  /*This will add Hover effect to .box */
        .fontSize;  /*This will inherit the style from the .fontSize class*/
        background:blue;
    }
}
```

Codepen Demo : **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHghJ**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood a question. But try using this construction

```
.language a {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    &:hover {color:blue;}
}
.language-2 a {
    .language a:hover;
}
```

Comment: So on hover which is &:hover{}, within that i want to extend the class from language so hover has the same styles, rather than retyping all the code again

Comment: @user3564005 Just put .language to your rule with the :hover and thats it

Comment: would that take the styles from language and copy into .language a:hover?